# STL file read using three.js issue

Tags: javascript, three.js, stl-format

I am able to read successfully stl file by three.js but problem is that is not showing exact color which is defined in the stl file. My code looks like:

```
var loader = new THREE.STLLoader();
loader.addEventListener( 'load', function ( event ) {
    var geometry = event.content;
    var material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial( { ambient: 0x555555, color: 0xAAAAAA, specular: 0x111111, shininess: 200 } );
    if (geometry.hasColors) {
        material = new THREE.MeshPhongMaterial({ color: 0xFFFFFF, specular: 0x111111, ambient: 0x555555, opacity: geometry.alpha, vertexColors: THREE.VertexColors });
    }
    var mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    mesh.position.x = x - w/2;
    mesh.position.y = y;
    mesh.position.z = - h + h/2 + z/2;
    //mesh.rotation.set( 0.5, 0, 0 );
    mesh.castShadow = true;
    mesh.receiveShadow = true;
    board.add(mesh);
} );

loader.load( fileName );
```

But its showing only black color after applying vertex color.
Any suggestion?

Comment: Do you have a light defined in the scene?

Comment: Yes. I added direction light and also spot light in the scene.

Comment: can you create a fiddle?

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/shiladittya/nswbfbu6/1/ This is fiddle which I created. I just paste my code.